# "c: Command not found" error

Tags: qt, makefile, qt5, yocto

I built qt5-toolchain for ARM arthitecture successfully.But I receive following error while compiling any qt application:

> Makefile:545: recipe for target 'moc_mainwindow.o' failed
>   Wl,-O1 -o Demo1 main.o mainwindow.o moc_mainwindow.o   -L/opt/poky/2.0.1/sysroots/cortexa7hf-vfp-vfpv4-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGLESv2 -lEGL -lpthread 
>   Makefile:199: recipe for target 'Demo1' failed
>   make: c: Command not found
>   make: [moc_mainwindow.o] Error 127 (ignored)
>   make: Wl,-O1: Command not found
>   make: [Demo1] Error 127 (ignored)

How can I solve this problem?
Thank for your reply...

Comment: add more informations. OS, build type (qmake/cmake), sources http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Some variable is not set correctly. `-Wl,-O1` is supposed to be an argument to a command running in a make recipe but the variable for the command itself (which comes before that) is missing and so make is seeing `-Wl,-O1` as the start of the line, stripping the `-` as "ignore errors from this command" (which is why it says `(ignored)` there) and then tries to run `Wl,-O1` as a command (and that obviously doesn't exist).

Comment: what version of qt you are using, from Jethro branch or master?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you have got the SDK and installed it in `/opt`, you will need to modify `qtcreator.sh` to add the environment setup.

so, locate `/opt/poky/1.6.1/environment-setup-cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi`

edit `/Qt5.5.1/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator.sh`

add this line before the Shebang
 `source /opt/poky/1.6.1/environment-setup-cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi`

Answer (score 0):

I think your qmake.config file is not configure properly.

follow this links : http://exploringbeaglebone.com/chapter11/

Prepare the build by creating a mkspecs file for armhf by modifying the linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ mkspecs file.

Edit the qmake.conf file to have “gnueabihf” entries rather than “gnueabi” entries.

Answer (score 0):

Editing qtcreator.sh is not necessary, but it may be convenient.

To fix the `make: c: Command not found` error you need to start Qt Creator from a shell where the Qt SDK environment setup script has been run.

For example:

```
. /opt/poky/2.0.1/environment-setup-cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi  
qtcreator > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

After you installed the SDK it said this:

> Each time you wish to use the SDK in a new shell session, you need to
>   source the environment setup script